# Exponential of the matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

I want to calculate the matrix exponential $e^{tA}$ of the matrix with the first row being $(0,1)$ and the second $ (-1,0)$. It would be sufficient if you would me the most important steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach to calculate the exponent $e^{tA}$ bases on the fact that this exponent solves the Cauchy problem
$$
\frac{d}{dt} Y(t) = AY(t), \quad t\in\Bbb R,\\Y(0)=I.
$$

Obviously, this problem splits to solving two Cauchy problems

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}  = A \begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y(t)\\-x(t)\end{pmatrix}, \quad t\in\Bbb R,\\x(0)=1,\quad y(0)=0\tag{1}.
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}  = A \begin{pmatrix}x(t)\\y(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}y(t)\\-x(t)\end{pmatrix}, \quad t\in\Bbb R,\\x(0)=0,\quad y(0)=1\tag{2}.
$$

Whatever method you use to solve problems (1) and (2) - passing to higher order equations, observing that $x^2(t)+y^2(t)=1$, etc -  you will arrive to solutions
$$\begin{pmatrix}x_1(t)\\y_1(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\cos t\\-\sin t\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix}x_2(t)\\y_2(t)\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}\sin t\\ \cos t\end{pmatrix}.$$

This allows to conclude that $$Y(t)=e^{tA} =  \begin{pmatrix}\cos t&\sin t\\-\sin t&\cos t\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: Do you know why wolframalpha says something very different? Just enter e^((0,1),(-1,0))

Comment: @Lipschitz By default wolframalpha applies functions elementwise. There's a special function called `MatrixExp` for matrix exponent; in your case use this query: `MatrixExp[{{0,1},{-1,0}}]`.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you should expand an exponent in Taylor series.

Then, you should understand, what happens with matrix, when it is exponentiated with power n.

The last step is to sum up all the matrices and realize, if there are Teylor series of some functions as an entries of the aggregate matrix.

Comment: I would add that the job gets a lot easier when the matrix is diagonalizable (why?)

Answer (score 4):

At first, you can easily check that
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1\\
-1&0\\
\end{bmatrix}^2=\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\0&-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

So
$$
\begin{aligned}
e^{tA}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^n}{n!}t^n &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^{2n}}{(2n)!} t^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{A^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} t^{2n+1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n I}{(2n)!}t^{2n} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n A}{(2n+1)!} t^{2n+1}
\end{aligned}$$

where $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\\\end{bmatrix}, \,I=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$ By Taylor series of cosine and sine function we get
$$e^{tA}=I\cos t + A\sin t = \begin{bmatrix}\cos t&-\sin t\\ \sin t&\cos t\end{bmatrix}.$$

It is similar to derive a imaginary exponential function use a Taylor series of exponential and trigometric functions.

Comment: For some reason this does not coincide with the wolframalpha result of e^((0,1),(-1,0))

Comment: The apparent discrepancy with WolframAlpha is explained [above](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/543992/exponential-of-the-matrix#comment1159060_544029): it is applying the exponential function elementwise, not taking a matrix exponential.

Answer (score 1):

You have $e^{tA}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \cfrac{A^k}{k!}$ so you need the powers of $A^k$.

Usually, the way you do this is that you find $P$ so that $PAP^{-1}=D+N$ so that $D$ is diagonal, $N$ is nilpotent and they commute. That's the Dunford decomposition. Then, $e^{tA}=P^{-1}e^{tD}e^{tN}P$ where $e^{tD}$ is easy to compute because it is diagonal so the exponential of the matrix is the matrix of the exponentials and $e^{tN}$ is easy to compute because there is a finite number of terms in the sum.

In your case, you will have $N=0$ since your matrix can be diagonalized.

Comment: Albeit correct, this is a bit of an overkill for this particular problem...

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is often best solved by diagonalising the matrix over the complex numbers, if you can (or triangularising otherwise). Here since $A^2=-I$ the matrix is diagonalisable with eigenvalues $\def\i{\mathbf i}\i,-\i$, and corresponding eigenvectors are
$v_1=\binom 1{-\i}$ and $v_2=\binom1\i$. Then $\exp(tA)\cdot v_1=e^{t\i}v_1$ and $\exp(tA)\cdot v_2=e^{-t\i}v_2$.

Now to convert back to the standard basis $e_1,e_2$ note that $e_1=\frac12(v_1+v_2)$ and $e_2=\frac\i2(v_1-v_2)$, so one gets
$$
 \begin{align}
 \exp(tA)\cdot e_1=\frac12(e^{t\i}v_1+e^{-t\i}v_2)
 &=\frac{e^{t\i}+e^{-t\i}}2e_1+\frac{-\i e^{t\i}+\i e^{-t\i}}2e_2
 \\&=\cos(t)e_1+\sin(t)e_2
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
 \begin{align}
 \exp(tA)\cdot e_2=\frac\i 2(e^{t\i}v_1-e^{-t\i}v_2)
 &=\frac{\i e^{t\i}-\i e^{-t\i}}2e_1+\frac{ e^{t\i}+ e^{-t\i}}2e_2
 \\&=-\sin(t)e_1+\cos(t)e_2.
\end{align}
$$
Therefore
$$ \exp(tA)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(t)&-\sin(t)\\\sin(t)&\cos(t)\end{pmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Can you explain to me why wolframalpha gives me a different result, when i enter e^((0,1),(-1,0))

Comment: Maybe WolframAlpha is just stupid? By the way, I see that I misread the question, taking columns $(0,1)$ and $(-1,0)$ instead of rows. So you should transpose my answer. The minus sign in $\exp(tA)$ must be in the same place as in $A$.

Comment: As for the stupid part, I'm really baffled that Wolfram, having apparently recognised a matrix exponential, gives $0$ as one of the eigenvalues.

Comment: This is very strange....cause Matlab gives the same result as wolframalpha

Comment: If you got [these results](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e^++%28%280%2C1%29+%2C%28+-1%2C0%29%29++) like I did, then one can conclude that WA just mapped the exponential function to individual matrix entries. I hope they don't do the same for matrix multiplication. And they dare to call themselves a **knowledge** engine. If Matlab does the same, shame on them too.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen As their help site says, they have a special function called `MatrixExp` to deal with matrix exponents.

Comment: OK, so [this is](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MatrixExp++%28t*%28%280%2C1%29+%2C%28+-1%2C0%29%29%29++) what you really need to type. But I still think interpreting $e^A$ for a matrix as anything else than a matrix exponential not very good for a site that aims to answer naturally formulated questions.